# How to map Exchange Web Service External Mail Id to Exchange Internal Message Id

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

There is a self written application (c#) in place communicating over EWS (Webservice) with Exchange.
Each mail item retrieved from EWS has a base64 encoded string as mail identifier.
The string is a concatenation of the GUID of the mailbox itself, some flags and other unknown stuff.
As observed in the application log the last 48 bit seem to represent a serial number that is increased for each new mail, because the base64 representation did that as well.

This looks the following way

```
AAMkADY4NGZiNmNmL[....]DruR5FpCowxZfCWAAAqi1dWAAA=
AAMkADY4NGZiNmNmL[....]DruR5FpCowxZfCWAAAqi1dXAAA=
AAMkADY4NGZiNmNmL[....]DruR5FpCowxZfCWAAAqi1dZAAA=
AAMkADY4NGZiNmNmL[....]DruR5FpCowxZfCWAAAqi1dYAAA=
AAMkADY4NGZiNmNmL[....]DruR5FpCowxZfCWAAAqi1daAAA=
AAMkADY4NGZiNmNmL[....]DruR5FpCowxZfCWAAAqi1dbAAA=
AAMkADY4NGZiNmNmL[....]DruR5FpCowxZfCWAAAqi1ddAAA=
AAMkADY4NGZiNmNmL[....]DruR5FpCowxZfCWAAAqi1deAAA=  
                                      ^^^^^^^^
```

My intention is to decode the base64 representation and interpret the bit section in such a way that I get exchange's internal message id. This is necessary to ease message tracking.

The problem I'm facing is that now matter in which way I try to interpret the bits I never get a value that is close to the internal message id.

Right now the internal message id in exchange is at **195XXXXXX**, but the binary value interpreted as an long  gives a value somewhere around **713XXXXXX** what makes absolutely no sense.

To make matter worse I observed a break in the sequence:

```
AAAqi1kKAAA=  
AAAqi1kLAAA=  
AAAqi1kMAAA=    (decimal 713775372)  
AAAqjUbTAAA=    (decimal 713901779)  
AAAqjUbUAAA=  
AAAqjUbVAAA=
```

That means that suddenly the serial number is increased by ~126'400

I can't imagine that exchange uses a different message id in EWS context than internally and is maintaining the mapping information somewhere.

Does anybody have an idea how to get the right message id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the EWS [ConvertId operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb799665%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) or EWS Managed API [ConvertId method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.convertid%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) is what you want to use to do the conversion. There's more information here: [Converting identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx#sectionSection4).